# Corona SDK - Moving Player Left and Right Using Touch (Code Included)

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk

Apologies if this was asked before, I tried searching to no avail. Anyways, I have some sort of logic error that is preventing my player object from moving left and right when I attempt to move it. Any tips would be appreciated, as I am a beginner to Lua. Thank you for your time.

```
function spawnPlayer()
player = display.newImage('player.png') 
player.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
player.y = display.contentHeight - player.height
player.name = 'player'
physics.addBody(player)
Score()
end

function Score()
score = display.newText('Score: ', 1, 0, native.systemFontBold, 14)
score.x = _W / 9
score.y = 0
score.text = score.text .. tostring(intscore)
Listeners('add')
end

function Listeners(event)

if event == 'add' then
    --Runtime:addEventListener("accelerometer", accelPlayer)
    --player:addEventListener("touch", touchPlayer)
    player:addEventListener('touch', touchPlayer)
    player:addEventListener('accelerometer', accelPlayer)
elseif event == 'remove' then
    Runtime:removeEventListener("accelerometer", accelPlayer)
    player:removeEventListener("touch", touchPlayer)
end
end

function touchPlayer:touch(event)

if isSimulator then

    if event.phase == "began" then
        moveX = event.x - player.x
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        player.x = event.x - moveX
    end

    if((player.x - player.width * 0.5) < 0) then
        player.x = player.width * 0.5
    elseif((player.x + player.width * 0.5) > display.contentWidth)
    then
        player.x = display.contentWidth - player.width * 0.5
    end 
end
end

function accelPlayer:accelerometer(event)

player.x = display.contentCenterX - (display.contentCenterX * (event.yGravity * 3))

if((player.x - player.width * 0.5) < 0) then
    player.x = player.width * 0.5
elseif((player.x + player.width * 0.5) > display.contentWidth)
then
    player.x = display.contentWidth - player.width * 0.5
end
end
```

Comment: What is happening?  What is not happening?  What do you expect to happen?  What have you done to try to figure out the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that. What's happening is that when I touch the player and swipe along the screen, nothing happens. I want the character to move left and right depending on where my finger moves. I've tried adding listeners in various places and on different objects, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print("in touch event")
if isSimulator then
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print("touch started")
        startX = event.x

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        local changeSinceLast = event.x - startX
        player.x = player.x + changeSinceLast 
        startX = event.x
        print("touch moved")

    end
```

**Update:**

If that prints nothing, then you have to look at what would cause `touchPlayer:touch(event)` to get called. It is `Listeners('add')`. Also, that function has `touchPlayer` but is touchPlayer exist when this function is called? So try:

```
function Listeners(event)
    if event == 'add' then
        print('adding touch listener:', touchPlayer)
        player:addEventListener('touch', touchPlayer)
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, but nothing happened. I appreciate the answer, though, thanks!

Comment: @user3456833 can you try the updated version? what gets printed?

Comment: Nothing is being printed, so I guess it isn't going into the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't assign touch listener on device. You have assigned touch listener only for simulator and you can not test touch event on simulator.
So assign it for device also and add below line in your begin condition.

display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )

Comment: Well, I first tried to add that under the "began" line as you said, and nothing happened, but then I commented out the "isSimulator" line and its corresponding "end," and it started to move when I touched the screen on my simulator. (I have a touch screen laptop.) 

Without the isSimulator line it works with and without the line of code you gave me. Would you know why?